# Get reference to the NSObject in an NSValue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsvalue

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` which contains `UIImageView` objects and `UIView`  keys.

When I am setting an `UIImageView` to the `NSMutableDictionary` I get the `NSValue` out from the `UIView` like this:

```
[viewImageMap setObject:anImage forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:aView]];
```

I want to know if there is anyway I can obtain the `UIView` reference back with the `NSValue` object. Something like this:

```
UIView *aView = (UIView *)[NSObject objectWithValue:aValue];
```

Comment: If the reason for packing the reference into an instance of `NSValue` is copying and strength, you can take into account the usage of `NSMapTable`(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMapTable), too. It is a more configurable dictionary, esp. it allows to assign a weak reference.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thank you. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `valueWith<Type>:` method, `NSValue` has a complementary method that returns the stored value in the appropriate type.

The one you need is [`nonRetainedObjectValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSValue/nonretainedObjectValue).

```
UIView * theView = [theValue nonRetainedObjectValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do so:

```
NSValue * myViewKey = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:myView];
UIView * myViewFromValue = (UIView*) myViewKey.nonretainedObjectValue
```

Comment: That's why the OP is using an `NSValue`, which does conform to `NSCopying`.

Comment: Sure, but I still think that's not a good idea in terms of architecture.

Comment: Thanks! but can you give me just one reason why it isn't a good idea?

Comment: I just edited my answer with an explanation on that.

Comment: It's _not_ retained by the `NSValue`; that's what **`Nonretained`** means.

Comment: No, but `NSDictionary` did. Take the code above, execute it, and look at the `myView` retainCount.

Comment: @JulienQuere Thanks. I'll verify this.

Comment: That's not an `NSDictionary` retaining the view. that's ARC, and it's because you've created two new strong references to the view when you unpack the value. The dictionary would only have a strong reference to the enclosing `NSValue`. @JLT

Comment: @JoshCaswell hmm, I am a bit confused. Why are there two new strong references when I unpack the value? I thought there's only one, which is the reference that I assigned to the unpacked value. -> UIView * theView = [theValue nonRetainedObjectValue];

Comment: There are two references in _Julien's_ code, @JLT: `myViewFromValue` and `mySecondViewFromValue`. The line you just wrote in that comment has only one, yes.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah I see, so you are referring to his code. Alright, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Hum, my bad, I was completely mistaken. I edit my answer. I'm truly sorry.